# white screen after exitApp

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

I am developing mobile app with ionic having splash & launch screen.

As of now, I am using below code to do my configurations & initiations and then hiding my splash screen.

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        // config & initiations
                ionic.Platform.ready( function() {
                if(navigator && navigator.splashscreen){
                    navigator.splashscreen.hide();
                }
        });
    });
```

Also, I am using double tap exit at first launch page with below snippet.

```
.factory('backcallFactory', ['$state','$ionicPlatform','$ionicHistory','$timeout',function($state,$ionicPlatform,$ionicHistory,$timeout){
        var obj={}
        obj.backcallfun=function(){
        var backbutton=0;
            $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function () {
                if ($state.current.name == "register") {
                     if(backbutton==0){
                        backbutton++;
                        window.plugins.toast.showShortCenter('Press again to exit');
                        $timeout(function(){backbutton=0;},5000);
                    }else{
                        navigator.app.exitApp();
                    }
                }
                else{
                        $ionicHistory.goBack();
                    }
            }, 100);
        }
        return obj;
    }])
```

So in launch page, if i click back button twice in 5 seconds and it gets closed.
I could see app is still open in open apps list. (first or last button in android phones).

The problem is, if I relaunch the app after double tap to exit , then it is showing white screen for a while and showing launch screen (but no splash screen). I checked in other popular apps having double tap to exit function are showing splash screen again and launch screen without white screen.

How can I achieve the same in my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. It works fine by downgrading to version 2.0.0 of cordova-plugin-splashscreen.

You can refer to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9374.

Comment: The url is not working and downgrading is not always the answer.